# Making numpy fsolve work on piecewise constant functions

Tags: python, numpy, numerical-methods

I'm trying to use fsolve to find intersection points of various parametric piecewise-defined functions:

```
max_price = 20.0
b = 0.5
consumption_func = lambda x,b : max_price if x <= b else max_price - (x-b)
func = lambda x: consumption_func(x,b)

bid_start, _, ier, msg = fsolve(lambda x: func(x) - 5.0, 0.0, xtol=0.0001, full_output=True)
```

However, the solver fails to find the intersection, even for this very simple function, if the starting point is in the range where the function is constant:

```
bid_start, _, ier, msg = fsolve(lambda x: func(x) - 5.0, b-0.1, full_output=True)

Out: array([0.4]) #starting point
msg='The iteration is not making good progress, as measured by the 
  improvement from the last ten iterations.'
```

and succeeds if it's in the non-constant range:

```
bid_start, _, ier, msg = fsolve(lambda x: func(x) - 5.0, b-0.1, full_output=True)

Out: array([15.5]) #correct answer
```

I guess it has something to do with the MINPACK algorithm that fsolve uses (probably gradient-based). In this simple case, I manage to bypass it by passing b as parameter, but in the future I'm planning to work with more sophisticated functions; any idea on how I can make fsolve work here?

Comment: To me, it seems quite obvious that all gradient based optimizers will fail on constant functions. But does it really make sense to take into account regions where the functions are constant? you can choose starting values and boundary conditions to avoid them.

You could also think about making your data smooth by convoluting it with with lorentzian for example, but this doesn't feel right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `fsolve` un-stuck by adding a random linear function to the equation. Use the solution of the randomized equation as the starting point for the original equation. The solution of randomized equation will sometimes be near the original of the real equation, which will result in convergence. If it doesn't; try again with another random.

See the `while` loop below, which runs until the flag `ier`  of `fsolve` is equal to 1 for the original equation, indicating success.

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import random
max_price = 20.0
b = 0.5
consumption_func = lambda x,b : max_price if x <= b else max_price - (x-b)
func = lambda x: consumption_func(x,b)

ier = 0
while ier != 1:
    k = random.uniform(-0.01, 0.01)
    func_random = lambda x: func(x) + k*x
    x_prelim = fsolve(lambda x: func_random(x) - 5.0, 0.0, xtol=0.01)
    bid_start, _, ier, msg = fsolve(lambda x: func(x) - 5.0, x_prelim, xtol=0.0001, full_output=True)

print(bid_start)
```

Comment: I tried it, and it generally depends whether the sign of k is the same as the "general gradient" of the function or not.

Comment: It surely does. That's why it's placed in the loop, so that values of either sign come up.